# c++ getopt() parameter identification

Tags: c++, getopt

Hi i'm testing out the default `getopt()` program that can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt).

When I run this code and I type for example `myProgram -c -b. -c` it takes `-b` as an parameter. As I understood it when reading about `getopt()`, characters that begin with `-` are treated as a special case. Can I get `getopt()` to instead of taking `-b` as an parameter to `-c` run `-c` without arg and then `-b` instead?

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1) 
    {
    char test = 111;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    switch (c) {
    case 'a':
        aflag = 1; break;
    case 'b':
        bflag = 1; break;
    case 'c':
    {
        cvalue = optarg;
        break;
    }
    case '?':
        if (isprint(optopt))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
        return 1;
    default:
        abort();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your option spec `"abc:"` has a colon `:` immediately after the `c` option informing `getopt` that `-c` on the command line requires an argument.  The fact that the argument supplied happens to be `-b` is irrelevant -- it *is* the argument.

The [`GNU` implementation of `getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) allows you to specify that the argument is optional by specifying a double colon `::` instead.

So, instead, try (untested)...

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "abc::")) != -1) {
```